# Pass criteria from a combo box to another combo box in access 2010

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying restrict the records in combo box 2 (cboNames) based on the selection of combo box 1 (cboClass).

Combo box 1 and combo box 2 are both based on records in the same table, tblNames.

Combo box 1's row source is set too

```
SELECT [tblNames].[ChildID], [tblNames].[Class] FROM tblNames;
```

Combo box 2's row source is set too:

```
SELECT tblNames.ChildID, tblNames.[Full Name], tblNames.Class FROM tblNames WHERE (((tblNames.Class)=[Forms]![frmInsertNewRecord]![cboClass]));
```

I was under the impression this should work but it obviously inst. Combo box 2 is blank.

Can anybody identify what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Once the value of the first combo box changes, you need to refresh the recordset of the second one.

You need to either hit the refresh button (<kbd>F5</kbd>) or add the following code in the `_AfterUpdate` event of the 1st box:

```
Private Sub cboClass_AfterUpdate() 
    Me.cboName.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Ive tried that and still nothing: i tried: Private Sub cboClass_AfterUpdate()

Me.cboClass.Requery

End Sub

Comment: No in the first combo box's after update (cboClass), you must write me.combo2.requery.

Comment: when i do this, i get a compile error: Method or data member not found

Comment: What is the name of your second combobox?

Comment: Then your statement should be `Me.cboName.Requery`.

Comment: Yeah i tried that also..still nothing. even when i run the query with the criteria as [Forms]![frmInsertNewRecord]![cboClass] it returns no data